# Is OpenOffice(4.1.3) with JDK11 in docker supported?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, openoffice.org

I have spring-boot application which uses openoffice service.

I have set up dockerfile for this application to start through docker.

In which I have used openjdk:11 image. On top of that I have installed openoffice.

When I am starting openoffice I am getting below error:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Is openoffice supported with JDK11?**

**If yes, then how to set JDK/JRE for openoffice in docker?**

Comment: Have you checked the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the container to make sure it's set appropriately?

Comment: Rosa, Yes I have checked and it is showing proper JDK path "/usr/local/openjdk-11".